# Resizing webview when android keyboard opens

Tags: javascript, android-studio, webview

I'm developing a chat using the webview of Android Studio. Every time the input text is selected, the keyboard opens resizes the input text and its div. I already configured the manifest as:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

And already tried:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I would like, when the keyboard is open, the input text and div will not be resized and remain the original size.

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="campoCorpo">
        <div class="wrapMsg">
        </div>  

        <div class="divMsg">
            <div class="alinhar">
                <input type="text" id="msgUsuario" class="inp">
                <div class="btnOk">
                </div>
            </div>          
        </div>      

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapMsg{
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    position: relative;
    height: 83%;
    width: 90%;
    top : 2%;
    left: 3%;
    border: 1px solid #b7b7b7;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 2% 2% 2% 2%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.divMsg{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #1098F7;
    height: 11%;
    width: 94%;
    bottom: 1%;
    left: 3%;
    display: table;
    border : 1px solid #4C6085;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.inp{
    margin-left: 1%;
    width: 82%;
    height: 75%;
}
.alinhar{
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;

}
input[type="text"]{
    border:0;
    outline: 0;
    border-radius: 3px
}
.btnOk{
    position: relative;
    width: 14%;
    height: 75%;
    background-color: #4C6085;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 2%;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
.campoCorpo{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #efefef;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can we see the HTML/CSS for the webview content?

Comment: Done, @ChrisG .

Comment: Almost all your size values are _percentages_. When the keyboard appears, then app area shrinks, and so does the webview. The obvious solution is to use absolute values for the dimensions of the input box.

Comment: And when the screen resolution of the cell phone changes? Absolute values ​​will not be a problem?

Comment: You don't have to use `px` values. Either use `em` /  `rem`, or calculate the values based on the available window size. Use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` for that.